# In Kalman filters why is it necessary to transform the systems dynamics matrix to the state transition matrix?

Tags: discrete-signals, kalman-filters

Previously when I have implemented Kalman filters I have used the transformation

$$
\mathbf{A(t)} = \mathcal{L}^{-1} \left( s \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{F} \right) ^{-1}
$$

to calculate the state transition matrix $\bf{A}$ from the system dynamics matrix $\bf{F}$.

Where the equation describing the state of the system is

$$
\vec{x_t} = \mathbf{F_t} \vec{x_{t-1}} + \mathbf{B_t} \vec{u_t} + \vec{w_t}
$$

and my prediction step calculation is

$$
\vec{x_{k|k-1}} = \mathbf{A} \vec{x_{k-1|k-1}} + B\vec{u_k}
$$

For example for simple sinusoidal Kalman filter started from the following equation of motion:

$ \ddot{x} = -\omega^2x $

So my matrix equation of motion was:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
  \dot{x} \\
  \ddot{x} \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
  0 & 1 \\
  -\omega^2 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
.
\begin{bmatrix}
  x \\
  \dot{x} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and my system dynamics matrix was

$$
F = \begin{bmatrix}
  0 & 1 \\
  -\omega^2 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I then performed the transformation $
\mathbf{A(t)} = \mathcal{L}^{-1} \left( s \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{F} \right) ^{-1}
$ to get the state transition matrix like so:

$$
A(t) = \begin{bmatrix}
  \cos(\omega t) & \dfrac{\sin(\omega t)}{\omega} \\
  -\omega \sin(\omega t) & \cos(\omega t) \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Where I then replaced $t$ with my sample time $T_s$ where $T_s = \dfrac{1}{F_s}$ where $F_s$ was my sample frequency.

I then used this to extract my sinusoidal signal.

My question is did I need to perform this transformation? And if I did, why did I have to do so?

I was reading the paper linked [here](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~rmf25/papers/Understanding%20the%20Basis%20of%20the%20Kalman%20Filter.pdf) where they attempt the explain the Kalman filter in simple way and they did no such transformation.

Comment: It's not clear to me, but I suspect you're doing it because your "equation of motion" is not a discrete-time equation, but you're applying a discrete time state-space system. Perhaps it's a sampling step? The state transition matrix doesn't change like that when starting from a discrete-time state-space equation and applying the KF equations.

Comment: I was following the derivation of a sinusoidal kalman filter in Fundamentals of Kalman filtering : a practical approach 2nd ed. by Paul Zarchan where they perform this operation. I assume this approach is not necessary in general then to take any arbitrary F matrix to an A matrix?

Comment: I don't have the book to hand currently to check if he explains why this step was taken.

Comment: Provided everything is discrete, then the transformation is not needed, yes.

Comment: Are you aware of how this transformation takes you from the continuous-time state-space to the discrete-time state-space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comments, there should be no need at all to do such a transformation if all of your equations start in discrete-time.

The equation
$$
 (s \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{F} )^{-1}
$$
is just the Laplace transform of the solution for the state equation:
$$
\dot{\vec{x_t}} = \mathbf{F} \vec{x_t} + \vec{w_t}
$$

However, I really can't see how $\mathbf{F}$ works in:
$$
\vec{x_t} = \mathbf{F_t} \vec{x_{t-1}} + \mathbf{B_t} \vec{u_t} + \vec{w_t}
$$
because this is a discrete-time equation, and the equation you're looking at generating the sinewave is continuous-time.

Can you clarify?

Comment: I'll need to check in the book from which I obtained the derivation, I don't have it to hand at the moment, but should have it in 4 hours. If $\left( s \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{F} \right)^{-1}$ is the Laplace transform, which I didn't realise, then the inverse laplace transform performed in $\mathcal{L}^{-1} \left( s \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{F} \right)^{-1}$ of this should bring you back to the original matrix. I presume that there is some trick being used to take it from continuous time to discrete time by Laplace transforming it and then performing the inverse transformation.

Comment: @SomeRandomPhysicist  That'd be my guess, but you'd have to check the book to make sense of it.

Comment: The inverse Laplace transform will give you the homogeneous (non-forced) solution to the differential equation --- in this case, a sine wave.

Comment: In the book I worked from, the author states that for a time invariant systems dynamics matrix one can derive the state transition matrix by performing the transformation $\mathcal{L}^{-1}([s\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{F}]^{-1})$ and cites Kalman and Bucy's 1961 paper "New Results in Linear Filtering and Prediction Theory"

Comment: Is this the general method for transforming a systems dynamics matrix with no time term present as the author suggests?

Comment: I doubt it. [That paper](http://www.pages.drexel.edu/~hgk22/courses/MEM636_638/KalmanBucy1961.pdf) is all done in continuous time.  There is something approaching what you're saying in (8) and (14) of the paper, but I can't see anywhere where they get a discrete-time KF.  The original paper was all continuous-time and differentiation / integration / Laplace transforms.

Comment: Ok, maybe I should check an updated edition of the book as I am working from the second edition. Are you aware of any general method for transforming from a time-invariant systems dynamics matrix to a discrete time one? For example such as the sinusoidal case above?

Comment: I have found a comprehensive discussion of this kind of problem in https://github.com/rlabbe/Kalman-and-Bayesian-Filters-in-Python/blob/master/07-Kalman-Filter-Math.ipynb where they introduce the solution I have used above and a number of other methods.

Comment: RIght, so that Python discussion uses equation (8), which makes sense (see under the section *The Matrix Exponential*). Nice writeup, that!

Answer (score 2):

The Laplace transform you show is equivalent to taking the matrix exponential of $\mathbf{F}$. Think about the properties of a continuous time state transition matrix, $\Psi(t,t)=I $, $$\Psi(t0,t1)\Psi(t1,t3)=\Psi(t0,t3),$$  and also that you can reverse time. $\mathbf{F}$ doesn't have those properties. It doesn't have to be invertible either.

$\mathbf{F}$ defines the continuous time differential equation at time $t$. It isn't the solution of the state at t+tau. One must also include the contribution of the control through $\mathbf{B}$, which is a bit more complicated. The solution is for $t$ doesn't assume that $t$ is evaluated at regular intervals but if we want to convert to discrete time, we evaluate at times corresponding to a discrete times.

If the state is discrete time and things like financial models are intrinsically discrete in time, that aren't derived from a continuous time system. One does not need to take the Laplace transform or matrix exponential. It only comes into play if the system was specified as a continuous time system

There is also the Kalman Bucy filter which is all continuous time.